# How can i delete data from cloud firestore , the database does not have document id

Tags: java, android

How can i delete data from cloud firestore , the database does not have document id

public class JournalRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JournalRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List journalList;

```
//
FirebaseFirestore firestore;
FirebaseAuth auth;

// constructor
public JournalRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Journal> journalList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.journalList = journalList;

    //
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public JournalRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.journal_row, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view, context);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JournalRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    Journal journal = journalList.get(position);
    String imageUrl;

    viewHolder.title.setText(journal.getTitle());
    viewHolder.description.setText(journal.getDescription());
    //viewHolder.name.setText(journal.getUserName());
    imageUrl = journal.getImageUrl();

    //timestamp format 13 minutes ago..
    String timeAgo = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(journal
            .getTimeAdded()
            .getSeconds() * 1000);
    viewHolder.dateAdded.setText(timeAgo);


    /*
     Picasso library to download and show image
     */
    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.cat)
            .fit()
            .into(viewHolder.image);

}

// count the journal list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return journalList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, description, dateAdded, name;
    public ImageView image;
    public ImageButton shareButton, deleteButton, editButton;
    public FirebaseFirestore db;
    String userId;
    String username;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context ctx) {
        super(itemView);
        context = ctx;

        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_journal_row_title);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_journal_row_decription);
        dateAdded = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_journal_row_date_added);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_journal_row_image);
        //name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_add_current_username);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        // delete Content
        deleteButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_journal_delete);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // delete
                db.collection("Journal").document(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .delete()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            }
                        });

            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

How can i delete data from cloud firestore , the database does not have document id